# Yoast SEO plugin open graph add meta tag to fetch Avatar from Author Page

Tags: author, avatar, open-graph

I'm trying to create a new og:image for author avatar when the users sharing their author profile page to Facebook.

I'm a newbie with WordPress, After searching for more than 6 months but i'm always failing.

My site is multi-authors and all what i need to add og:image meta tag for author.php "author profile", I'm stuck and I really get tired from searching.

When our users trying to share his profile..the avatar image not coming up! because Facebook can't find the author avatar og:image!

Plugins i'm using : [Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/), [Simple Local Avatars](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-local-avatars/), [AddToAny Share Buttons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-to-any/).

I tried to use wpseo_opengraph_image filter, but not working.

This is code I'm using:

```
function custom_author_og_image() {
    if ( is_author ( ) ) {
    $author = get_queried_object();
        $image_attributes = get_avatar_url( $author->user_email, 'full' );
        if ( $image_attributes !== false ) {
            return $image_attributes[0];
        }
    }
}
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_image', 'custom_author_og_image', 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to check if any og:image duplicate in your `<head>` tag.

Or you can try to increase the priority of filter hook. Example below, using the filter with priority = 99 (almost latest).

`add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_image', 'custom_author_og_image', 99);`

Comment: at all i can't find inside the author page any `<head>`  tags for og:image ! my authors url like that https://www.example.com/portfolio/username/

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer and i would like to sharing it with you, but i have another small problem. Now i can get the author avatar IF he has 1 post at least!! and the authors with 0 posts Facebook can't fetch his avatar image!! Strange thing and i don't know how to fix this.

anyway this is the code i found.

```
add_action('wpseo_head', 'add_fb_og', 5);

function add_fb_og() {
        if ( is_author ( ) ) {
$my_custom_avatar = get_avatar(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 200 );
$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHTML($my_custom_avatar);
$nodes = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');

    ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $nodes->item(0)->getAttribute('src'); ?>" />
    <?php
    }
}
```